# Solving cubic equation for real roots

Tags: equation-solving, complex, polynomials

I'm looking to solve the following cubic equation for x:

$\beta\, x^3 - \gamma \,x = c$. I have plugged in some sample values ($\beta = 2$, $\gamma = 5$ and $c = 2$). When I try to solve this equation using mathematica's Solve[] function, I get one real root and 2 complex roots. However, I have tried plotting the equation for these values, and can clearly see there should be 3 real roots. How can I obtain them. I am sure the roots are real, but mathematica gives me back complex roots.

Thanks.

Comment: Try `Solve[2 x^3 - 5 x == 2, x] // N // Chop`... If you want it in symbolic/exact form, do `Simplify[x /. Solve[2 x^3 - 5 x == 2, x] // ComplexExpand]` (I'm sure this has been asked before and probably answered by Artes)

Comment: For the record, `x/.Solve[2 x^3 - 5 x == 2, x]` gives three REAL roots, which are expressed in terms of radicals and (of necessity) use the imaginary unit sqrt(-1). That is not the same thing as having two complex roots.

Comment: I'm too late the hero, but: read up on *[casus irreducibilis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original equation is in the form of a "depressed cubic" $x^3-(\gamma/\beta)x-c/\beta=0$. When the discriminant, $4 \beta \gamma^3 - 27 c^2 \beta^2$, is positive, the equation has three real roots. In this case, the roots may be written as follows:

$2\sqrt{-p/3}~{\rm Cos}[\frac{1}{3}{\rm ArcCos}[3q \sqrt{-3/p}~/~(2p)]-2\pi k/3]$,

where $p=-\gamma/\beta<0$, $q=-c/\beta$, and $k=0,1,2$. No complex square roots required.

Comment: Let `p[x_] := β x^3 - γ x - c`. `Reduce[ Discriminant[ p[x], x] > 0, { β, γ, c}]` yields `(β < 0 && γ < 0 && -((2 Sqrt[ γ^3/β])/(3 Sqrt[3])) < c < ( 2 Sqrt[ γ^3/β])/(3 Sqrt[3])) || (β > 
    0 && γ > 0 && -((2 Sqrt[γ^3/β])/(3 Sqrt[3])) < c < (2 Sqrt[γ^3/β])/(3 Sqrt[3]))`. While `Discriminant[p[x] /. {β -> 2, γ -> 5, c -> 2}, x]` yields `568`.

Comment: @kennyColnago can you explain what you are defining as the discriminant and how you arrived at 4βγ^3−27c^2β^2. The definition I found (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolynomialDiscriminant.html) appears to require that you already know what the roots are to calculate it (I'm  probably wrong). If you could also supply a reference for the statement "When the discriminant, is positive, the equation has three real roots" that would be really helpful.

Comment: @MHH Equations 7 and 8 in the MathWorld link you mention show how to calculate the discriminant. In this case, $a_3=\beta$, $a_2=0$, $a_1=-\gamma$, and $a_0=-c$. The wikipedia article [Discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) gives a similar presentation at the top of the page, and section 6.2 discusses the "Nature of the roots".

Answer (score 1):

The 3 roots only appear to be imaginary. If you enter `N[Chop[sol]]`, you will see that the results are all real. If you are just looking for the values, then the function `NSolve` would be more appropriate here. The closed form solutions for the cubic contain nested square roots. This is why the solution has complex numbers.

Comment: `ComplexExpand@ToRadicals@Table[Root[-2 - 5 #1 + 2 #1^3 &, k], {k, 3}]`